# What does "你究竟是还看了些 什么东西" mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, word-choice, word

So I was reading a novel and I don't get "你究竟是还看了些 什么东西" does it mean "what else did you see?" Or would it be more like "what else did you learn?"

Comment: 是 seems out of place in 你究竟(是)还看了些 什么东西

Comment: Can you provide more context?

Comment: 是 seems redundant, the sentence is already completed with the verb 看

Answer (score 1):

Let's break up the sentence into segments: 你 究竟是 还 看了些 什么东西?

Now let's eliminate "究竟是", the remaining sentence is 你 还 看了些 什么东西? - What else you have seen?

究竟 can mean "after all", "actually" or "ever". The former two meanings fit this sentence well - After all (Actually), what else you have seen? Tang Ho's comment is correct, "是" can be dropped without affecting the sentence - 你究竟还看了些什么东西?

Answer (score 0):

The direct translation is "what else did you see?" But the form of this statement is not usual. It is possible to have more potential meaning in different situations. Need more content.

Answer (score 0):

Need more context. But to me, it means "After all, you have read something", like a teacher speaking to a naughty student, expressing his surprise that the student does has some knowledge.